# MIT license, did I attribute it correctly inside my answer

Tags: discussion, attribution, mit-license

As part of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41740204/3231537) today, I took a code originally from John Resig, and implemented some changes for the OP. As this question still uses the code, I kept the MIT license from John in there (as well in the code snippet as in the answer)

Is this enough, should I add a link to the original source code (or to the JS Ninja book)?

The change in itself was just a minor one, should I mark where the changes were made in bigger detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, so I can't say whether it is *necessary* or not, but **it never hurts to include a link to the original source**, whether for legal reasons or for people who just want to follow-up and see it in its original context.

You can throw it in easily here:

> The changes required for John's code (originally from [his JS Ninja book](http://example.com/)), would be something similar to this:

You don't need to mark the changes for any type of legal or licensing reasons. It is enough to indicate the original source.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, the original OP had include the link to his blog, so I added it as suggested, but also linked to the book itself), thanks :)